# Error while installing bootstrap 4 beta, error code 4048

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4

When I tried to install **bootstrap 4 beta** in Angular CLI 1.3.1, This is just fresh installation for trying out some CSS related stuff.

*It is giving bellow error even though I am running command as Administrator.*

**[Updated]** Replaced screenshot with debug info

Here is npm debug info

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'F:\\Programming\\JS\\Nodejs8\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Viraj\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'bootstrap@4.0.0-beta' ]
2 info using npm@5.4.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose npm-session 75609d81f090ff57
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap 1977ms (from cache)
8 silly pacote version manifest for bootstrap@4.0.0-beta fetched in 3321ms
9 silly install loadIdealTree
10 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
11 silly install loadShrinkwrap
12 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
13 silly resolveWithNewModule bootstrap@4.0.0-beta checking installable status
14 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents 572ms (from cache)
15 silly pacote range manifest for fsevents@^1.0.0 fetched in 650ms
16 silly resolveWithNewModule fsevents@1.1.2 checking installable status
17 silly pacote trying https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.2.tgz by hash: sha512-Sn44E5wQW4bTHXvQmvSHwqbuiXtduD6Rrjm2ZtUEGbyrig+nUH3t/QD4M4/ZXViY556TBpRgZkHLDx3JxPwxiw==
18 silly pacote https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.2.tgz extracted to C:\Users\Viraj\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9612-98a2724c\unpack-ed2bd6af by content address 17058ms

-- deleted someline to fit in stackoverflow----
1015 silly decomposeActions unbuild fsevents
1016 silly decomposeActions remove fsevents
1017 silly decomposeActions fetch fsevents@1.1.2
1018 silly decomposeActions extract fsevents@1.1.2
1019 silly decomposeActions preinstall fsevents@1.1.2
1020 silly decomposeActions build fsevents@1.1.2
1021 silly decomposeActions install fsevents@1.1.2
1022 silly decomposeActions postinstall fsevents@1.1.2
1023 silly decomposeActions finalize fsevents@1.1.2
1024 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json fsevents@1.1.2
1025 silly decomposeActions unbuild bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1026 silly decomposeActions remove bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1027 silly decomposeActions fetch bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1028 silly decomposeActions extract bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1029 silly decomposeActions preinstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1030 silly decomposeActions build bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1031 silly decomposeActions install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1032 silly decomposeActions postinstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1033 silly decomposeActions finalize bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1034 silly decomposeActions refresh-package-json bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1035 silly install executeActions
1036 silly doSerial global-install 894
1037 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Viraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
1038 verbose lock using C:\Users\Viraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-8779bf6cfde4176a.lock for F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\.staging
1039 silly doParallel extract 894
1040 silly extract fsevents@1.1.2
1041 silly pacote trying fsevents@https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.2.tgz by hash: sha512-Sn44E5wQW4bTHXvQmvSHwqbuiXtduD6Rrjm2ZtUEGbyrig+nUH3t/QD4M4/ZXViY556TBpRgZkHLDx3JxPwxiw==
1042 silly extract bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1043 silly pacote trying bootstrap@https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.tgz by hash: sha512-I/r3fYtUZr+rUNkh8HI+twxZ56p6ehNn27eA1XSebLVQKAJ2xZHnEvZrSR+UR2A/bONcd9gHC3xatVhQlH6R6w==
1044 silly pacote bootstrap@https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.tgz extracted to F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\.staging\bootstrap-6d9b8e3a by content address 5060ms
1045 silly pacote fsevents@https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-1.1.2.tgz extracted to F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-1488e69a by content address 16992ms
1046 silly doReverseSerial unbuild 894
1047 silly unbuild bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1048 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~preuninstall: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1049 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~uninstall: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1050 verbose unbuild rmStuff bootstrap@4.0.0-beta from F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules
1051 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~postuninstall: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta

-- deleted someline to fit in stackoverflow----

1568 silly doParallel preinstall 894
1569 silly preinstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1570 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~preinstall: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1571 silly doSerial build 894
1572 silly build bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1573 info linkStuff bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1574 silly linkStuff bootstrap@4.0.0-beta has F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules as its parent node_modules
1575 verbose linkBins bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1576 verbose linkMans bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1577 silly doSerial global-link 894
1578 silly doParallel update-linked 894
1579 silly doSerial install 894
1580 silly install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1581 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~install: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1582 silly doSerial postinstall 894
1583 silly postinstall bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1584 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.0.0-beta~postinstall: bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
1585 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Viraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-8779bf6cfde4176a.lock for F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\.staging
1586 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
1587 verbose cwd F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox
1588 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
1589 verbose argv "F:\\Programming\\JS\\Nodejs8\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Viraj\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bootstrap@4.0.0-beta"
1590 verbose node v8.4.0
1591 verbose npm  v5.4.0
1592 error path F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json
1593 error code EPERM
1594 error errno -4048
1595 error syscall unlink
1596 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
1596 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\Projects\CSS\FlexBox\flexBox\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
1596 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'F:\\Projects\\CSS\\FlexBox\\flexBox\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json\'',
1596 error   errno: -4048,
1596 error   code: 'EPERM',
1596 error   syscall: 'unlink',
1596 error   path: 'F:\\Projects\\CSS\\FlexBox\\flexBox\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json' }
1597 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
1598 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Here is my NPM info

```
node version is 8.4.0
npm version is 5.4
OS Architecture 64 bit
OS Windows 10 Pro
```

Thanks 
let me know , if you need more information.

Comment: For next time, could you copy/paste the error instead of giving a screenshot? It's way easier for us. And it helps others with the same error find this post on google.

Comment: Sure, didn't realized, as text easily will get indexed in google than image. Thanks for notifying me. next time onward I will take care of these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read in the error itself:

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

To do this, right click on your windows menu icon (usually bottom left) and instead of choose Command line, pick Command line (Admin). Note that the exact wording could be different, I am not using an english version.

There seems to be a couple other people with the same problem. Please see if any solution found [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826) can help.

To sum up the solutions for prosperity:

- Clear npm cache
- Disable antivirus
- Make sure no program is using the files (sublime text seemed to lock)
- Unistall and reinstall nodeJS and NPM
- Update/Downgrade NPM

Comment: After doing everything above step, nothing helped me but when I downgraded to npm 5.3.0 and important here is after machine restart, it worked. So strange behavior. But yes , you answer helped to go in some direction and resolve issue at somewhat extent ( I cant confirm hard n fast that , these steps will works for others). Anyway Thanks.

Comment: Seems like there was problem due to I was using power shell in VS code. By changing to normal console (windows default cmd). This works.